# Pass backspace key pressed event to the applet and stop it propagation

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a Java applet on web page that allows editing text. When user tries to modify text, pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd> button, browser forwards to previous page. If filter backspace pressing like:

```
var a = function () {
        var event = window.event;
        if (event.keyCode == 8){
            alert('backspace');
            return false;
        }
}
document.onkeydown = a;
```

then backspace doesn't propagate to applet, thus not modifying text.
The question is how to pass event to the applet and stop further propagating?

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` on your function. Typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I find solution in using [jQuery sendkeys plugin](http://bililite.com/blog/2008/08/20/the-fnsendkeys-plugin/). Since using jQuery in our project is not an option I'll try to rewrite it in plain javascript.

Comment: It uses some sophisticated manipulations with hidden textarea to simulate key press

Comment: Wow, okay, well, I'm glad you figured it out.  IE really frustrates me sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (event.keyCode === 8)
{
   var newEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
   newEvent.initKeyEvent(                                                                                      
                 "keypress",        //  in DOMString typeArg,                                                           
                  true,             //  in boolean canBubbleArg,                                                        
                  true,             //  in boolean cancelableArg,                                                       
                  null,             //  in nsIDOMAbstractView viewArg,  Specifies UIEvent.view. This value may be null.     
                  false,            //  in boolean ctrlKeyArg,                                                               
                  false,            //  in boolean altKeyArg,                                                        
                  false,            //  in boolean shiftKeyArg,                                                      
                  false,            //  in boolean metaKeyArg,                                                       
                   8,               //  in unsigned long keyCodeArg,                                                      
                   0);              //  in unsigned long charCodeArg); 
   document.getElementById('myjavaapplet').dispatchEvent(newEvent);
}
```

Comment: Note that iniKeyEvent is "Gecko-specific; the DOM 3 Events working draft uses initKeyboardEvent instead" ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent )

Comment: I'm programming for IE. The Event object returned by document.createEventObject dosn't have method 'initKeyboardEvent'

Answer (score 0):

```
if (event.keyCode === 8)
{
    var newEvent = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
    newEvent.initUIEvent( 'keypress', true, true, window, 1 );
    newEvent.keyCode = 8;
    document.getElementById('myjavaapplet').dispatchEvent(newEvent);
}
```

Comment: according to IE8 JS debugger event object has only following methods: getAttribute, setAttribute and removeAttribute. I've tried setting attributes listed in initUIEvent but it did't work(

Answer (score 0):

```
// assumes IE8, but you could write detection code based on if (document.createEventObject)

if (event.keyCode === 8)
{
    var newEvent = document.createEventObject();
    newEvent.keyCode = 8;
    document.getElementById('myjavaapplet').fireEvent('onkeypress',newEvent);
}
```